# Dynamic input datepicker - not working as expected

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have dynamically generated input fields with class='freeze-date' that only works on the 1st datepicker input-field generated. I have the code @ http://jsfiddle.net/Someguy2k/L9nvs/3/

Thanks

Comment: As François Wahl said: the markup is invalid. You should always validate the markup as the first thing there are several services for that. being http://validator.w3.org my favorite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several issues with your injected markup. All of you `id` attributes in each row of elements have the same value.
Not only is that invalid HTML but also results in side-effects such as this one.

jQuery will look for an id and stop when it finds the first match.
I fixed that particular issue with your calendar by adding the `i` value as an additional value to the `id` attribute.

```
...  id='freezeby" + i + "'  ...
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/e8rMv/)

If you find other elements are behaving the same when interacted with it is most likely due to the same reasons as I have seen the other `id` attributes also having the same issue.

**Using Live()**

In addition, you are using `live()`. Live has several issues and all the drawbacks are listed in the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Memeory leaks, unexpected loss of events bindings, stopPropagation() doesn't work due to the way `live()` bubbles events and more.

Since jQuery 1.7 `live()` has been deprecated and `on()` is preferred. For your version it is preferred to use [**bind()**](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) for binding events to static elements and [**delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to bind events to dynamic elements.

Comment: that worked and it's always the simple things that get me... what are the other issues with the injected markup? I'm not experienced with JQ - thank you for the help and critic.

Comment: You are welcome. Regarding the HTML, make sure you add some unique value to each element you generate in your loop, I used the `i` value as that is what you used in other places already. Regarding jQuery, the most important thing you will find is their online documentation. It is very clear and is always updated with latest news on deprecated functionality and so on. I linked all of the relevant documentation in the answer. Have fun :)